# Google BigQuery - Strange Query error in github timeline table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have one query performed in Google Big Query service, with the misunderstood error

> Error: Field 'evt.repository_name' not found in table 'evt'.

, because the field exists in table where the error was pointed. Anybody can help me to solve this?

Query:

```
    select nname 
    from (
         select evt.repository_name nname, count(evt.payload_issue_id) issues_count
         from [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] evt 
           where upper(repository_language)='JAVA'
          AND evt.repository_name in (
              select name from (

                     select evt1.repository_name name, count(evt1.payload_commit_id) commits_count
                     from [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] evt1 
                     where upper(repository_language)='JAVA'
                     group by name
                     order by commits_count desc 
                     limit 20  
                               ) 
             as foo2)    
    group by nname
    order by issues_count desc 
    limit 20 ) as foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one works:

```
  select nname 
    from (
         select repository_name as nname, count(payload_issue_id) as issues_count
         from [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] as evt 
           where upper(repository_language)='JAVA'
          AND repository_name in (
              select name from (

                     select evt1.repository_name name, count(evt1.payload_commit_id) commits_count
                     from [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] evt1 
                     where upper(repository_language)='JAVA'
                     group by name
                     order by commits_count desc 
                     limit 20  
                               ) 
             as foo2)    
    group by nname
    order by issues_count desc 
    limit 20 ) as foo
```